# Relay to Mains lightswitch

Tags: relay

So I purchased a 4 channel Relay which handles AC250V 10A ; DC30V 10A.
But am I able to connect this to replace a light switch so I can automate it?  My bedroom runs on 15 amps.

[image: relay board]

[http://amazon.com/gp/product/B00VHVIBAM?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VHVIBAM)

Comment: You can. But if it's a wall switch, it may be required to have an electrician do this, in your country. The 15Amps is the maximum current. Unless you are using a 2000 Watt light bulb, you won't reach the 10A limit of the relay. Remember to be careful, while working with mains voltage.

Comment: I have been working with mains lately, but I just don't know if the relay will blow out with the 15 amps.  But thank you!

Comment: It will only, if you have a device attached that uses more than 10 amps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mains electrical wiring not Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## All mains electrical work should be performed by a fully qualified electrician.

Yes, this relay board will easily switch a light bulb.

A note on current: A single 100 Watt incandescent globe will only draw 0.83 Amps at 120V AC (0.416 Amps at 240V AC). The equation I used: I=P/V. You would start coming close to the maximum rating after 10 globes (although I advise staying well below the maximum).

You mention that your bedroom runs on 15 Amps, which I assume means that the mains runs through a 15 Amp circuit breaker (or fuse). This circuit breaker will trip if the total current to all devices after it exceeds 15 Amps.

A [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33312/104097) was asked by Matthieu Napoli over on the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange site. There are a number of high quality answers there that would be helpful for you. Worthiest to mention is [Cybergibbons answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/33366/104097) where he recommends using the [PowerSwitch Tail](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/) as a very safe way of switching mains voltage. You don't need an electrician when using the PowerSwitch Tail providing the light you are controlling has the matching plugs.